# Como passar um ponteiro de função por parâmetro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, funções, função-anônima

Preciso que seja passado pelo `argv[]`, na função main, o nome de uma função que será chamada pela mesma.

Não posso fazer comparações de *strings*, então devo fazer a chamada com variáveis.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
typedef void (*func)(void);
void A (void){ printf("*funcao A*\n"); }
void B (void){ printf("*funcao B*\n"); }
void fun(func fc){ 
    fc(); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){ 
        fun(argv[i]);   
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Desta forma o algorítimo compila mas não executa.

Comment: Eu consigo compilar, mas nem sequer entra o ciclo `for`

Comment: `argc` não é _zero-based_? Nesse caso o `for` tem que começar em `i = 0`.

Comment: Já iniciei em i = 1 porque em argv[0] tem diretório do arquivo.

Comment: Se o exercício pede para *passar o* **nome** *de uma função*, acho difícil escapar de fazer comparações de strings em algum momento. Dá uma investigada nesse requisito.

Comment: @FightForWhat Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não consegui nem compilar.

```
(func)argv[i]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/CastError.c).

Não transforma magicamente uma *string* em um ponteiro para função. É impossível fazer esta transformação direta.

O melhor que você pode conseguir é montar uma tabela de *lookup* com os nomes das funções e os seus respectivos ponteiros. De alguma forma vai haver uma comparação de *strings*. Dá até para usar uma tabela *hash* para isto mas mesmo assim haverá comparação.

Se você entendeu certo o requisito quem criou este requisito ou não sabe como um computador funciona ou está pensando em algum truque capcioso.

Em linguagens que possuem metadados fica mais simples. Mas no fundo haverá comparação mesmo que você não esteja vendo ela. É possível usar alguma [biblioteca em C para conseguir isto](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) se carregar um módulo externo. Em DLLs existe algum metadado. Mas uma comparação ocorrerá, você só não verá ela.

Comment: Meu professor de estrutura de dados ele até criou o primeiro sistema operacional no Rio Grande do Sul.

Comment: Não to defendendo o velho mas tem coisas que ele é bem sem noção...

Comment: Tem um outra possibilidade. Você não entendeu o requisito. Mas acredito mais em ser alguma proposta capciosa.